# jQuery animations within a function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to have a function called in an onclick handler, within an IF statement... Confused?

I would be too, the code below should help... For some reason, I get  `"gotoIt is not defined"` in FireBug.

I think people keep misunderstanding the question :P... the full code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- REQUIRE COMMON VARIABLE FILE -->
<? require 'sys/common.php'; ?>
<title><? echo $projectName; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        if ($(window).width()<1259) { //Small
            function gotoIt(x,y) {
                $('.elements').animate({
                    left: x+'px',
                    top: y+'px'
                }, 500, function() {
                });
            }
        } else { //Large
            function gotoIt(x,y) {
                $('.elements').animate({
                    left: x+'px',
                    top: y+'px'
                }, 500, function() {
                });
            }
        };

    });
</script>
</head>

<body onload="">
<!-- SITE CONTAINER -->
<div class="section">
    <!-- CENTRAL CONTAINERS -->
        <ul class="elements" style="height:4884px; width:6000px;">
            <li>1<br/><a href="#" onclick="javascript:gotoIt(1620,1130);">Next</a></li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li>12</li>
            <li>13</li>
            <li>14</li>
            <li>15</li>
            <li>16</li>
            <li>17</li>
            <li>18</li>
            <li>19</li>
            <li>20<a name="test"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
   body {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 62.5%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    /* CONTAINERS */
    div.section{
        border:1px black solid;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        position:relative;
        clear:both;
    }
        div.section h3{
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }
        div.section li{
            float:left;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        div.pane{
            overflow:auto;
            clear:left;
            margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
            position:relative;
            width:826px;
            height:322px;
        }


    ul.elements{
        background-color:#5B739C;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    ul.elements li{
        width:1280px;
        height:815px;
        font-weight:bolder;
        border:1px black solid;
        text-align:center;
        margin-right:200px;
        margin-bottom: 200px;
        background-color:#DDD;
        font-size: 100px;
    }

    #pane-options ul.elements li{
        margin:5px;
    }
```

Comment: Edited my answer, and heres a copy: http://jsfiddle.net/P9bNk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the function, then call it.

```
function gotoIt(x,y) {
  $('.elements').animate({
    left: x+'px',
    top: y+'px'
  }, 500);
}

if ($(window).width()<1259) { //Small
  gotoIt(/* parameters here */);
} else { //Large
  gotoIt(/* parameters here */);
}
```

Edit 3: is this what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width()<1259) { //Small
        (function(x, y) {
            $('.elements').animate({
                left: x+'px',
                top: y+'px'
            }, 500);
        })(20,20); //arguments x and y
    } else { //Large
        (function(x, y) {
            $('.elements').animate({
                left: x+'px',
                top: y+'px'
            }, 500);
        })(-20,-20); //arguments x and y
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks but the **IF** statement needs to wrap around the functions. Unless there is a better way for me to do it?

Comment: You could use anonymous functions. Ill edit my post to include it.

Comment: No, the if doesn't need to wrap around the function. If blocks do not create their own scope. Wrapping if around the function does nothing, really. The function will only run when called, and the way that digitalFresh has it does what you want.